# Yii2 enablePrettyUrl only for modules

Tags: php, rest, yii2, url-routing

I have a yii2 project which is using a default URL rule (http://example.com?r=controller/action&id=1)

I want to add a REST API module in the project and enable the pretty URL format (http://example.com/controller/action?id=1) only for this module.

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => [
                    'api/default',
                ]

            ],
        ],
    ]
```

When I configure UrlManager enablePrettyUrl=>true, that also changes the URL format project wide. We have hardcoded URLs in default URL format in the frontend which cannot be changed now as the codebase has grown exponentially.

Is there a way to configure the URL rules only for REST API module and use default URL format for other modules.

Comment: Did u try creating a new config file with updated urlManager setting under module directory and include it in Module Init function like `\Yii::configure($this, require(__DIR__ . '/config.php'));`

Comment: @ck_arjun: No, I will try that.